# How to change all layouts background color in android

Tags: android

I am new in android. I want change my all relative layout background color on selection of navigation drawer item (change Background) at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get a reference from your relative layout and call the 
method `setBackgroundColor()`

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.id);       
layout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android color or your color));
```

Comment: Hi DeKoServidoni,  this code set only one layout background color ?